# Laravel Livewire (Class name must be a valid object or a string)

Tags: php, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I got an error "Class name must be a valid object or a string" on "public/index.php: 51".

I'm using laravel 10.26.2, PHP 8.2.8, and livewire 3.

Here is my livewire controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Todo;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Livewire\Component;

class TodoList extends Component
{
    public $todos = [];
    public $task;

    function mount(){
        $this->fetchTodos();
    }

    function fetchTodos(){
        $this->todos = Todo::all()->reverse();
    }
    
    public function addTodos(){
        $this->validate([
            'task' => 'required'
        ]);
        $todo = new Todo();
        $todo->title = $this->task;
        $todo->description = 'some description';
        $todo->due_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(2);
        $todo->save();
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.todo-list');
    }

}
```

I think the problem comes from the `fetchTodos()` function, because when I deleted it, my app runs fine. I finish try to use `php artisan config:cache` and I still face the same error.

Comment: use `php artisan tinker` and see if `Todo::all()->reverse();` actually runs fine without errors.

Comment: thanks @BagusTesa !, the problem is on the $this->todos, i must convert the query with toArray() first and it work just fine

Comment: `$todos = [];` - ahhh yeah.. its an array. if it was `$todos = collect();` then you can assign `Collection` into it.